# How can I delete Heroku Buildpacks?

Tags: python, heroku, buildpack

I am new to **Heroku** and I'm having trouble during deployment.

I want to deploy a Python app.

I just want to delete my Buildpacks as I don't know BUILDPACK_URL or how to get it and I've reached Buildpacks limit.

Comment: Log in to heroku on your browser. Open your app, Click the settings In your heroku settings , scroll down and you can remove from there. If your using django, this is a good video guide on deploying *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kvTsCskJA0*

Answer (score 1):

you can manage buildpacks for app in `https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<app_name>/settings`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Heroku CLI installed you can simply do this with the command

```sh
heroku buildpacks:clear
```

or if you have multiple apps

```sh
heroku buildpacks:clear --app <app-name>
```